# Android Video and Image filtering

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-videoview, android-video-player

I'm looking for a Library that supports editing videos and images using some sort of instagram filters.
I will be using it to save data also (not only at runtime)

Lately I have been reading about the ffmpeg library.
Is there any other effective library to do so?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want instagram filters tutorial then have a look at this link

[Instagram Image Filters](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-building-image-filters-like-instagram/)

Now i dont know any such alternative of ffmpeg if you know c++ then make your own native library according to your needs

these are some other github projects and libraries you can use to save your time

[Photo Editor](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor)

[iQuePhoto](https://github.com/iQueSoft/iQuePhoto)

these are some video editing libs/projects

[Video Editor](https://github.com/JaySardhara/Video-Editor)

[FFMPEG Video Editor](https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android)